# How to get user input passed through to my query and display results in a label

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have another question posted where my query would not return the results into my sealresult Label.  So I figured to ask it in a different way because I still cannot figure this out.  I have the following code, it runs perfectly when the button "Search" is clicked and returns the query result. However, I have a textBox with an Id of receiptbox and I want to enable an user to input text and that be placed into the query to gather the result into the sealresult Label. How do I accomplish this?  I want user input where it says RE00007544 from a textbox labeled receiptbox.

```
protected void receiptbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void sealresultquery_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{

}
protected void searchbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sealresult.Text = "";
    string connString = @"Data Source=SQL;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User ID=admin;Password=******";
    string query = "Select seal1 from dbo.RECEIPTHEADER where receipt = 'RE00007544'";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    using (conn)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

            while(reader.Read())
            {
                sealresult.Text += reader[0].ToString();

            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            querystatus.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, I think the simplest modification to the code you provided would be:

```
string query = "Select seal1 from dbo.RECEIPTHEADER where receipt = '" + receiptbox.Text + "'";
```

However, it's not the most secure way.  You shouldn't be this trusting with user input.

Comment: This worked! I am not too worried about SQL injections because this will be on a local server and only used by one user.  Nothing will be exposed publicly.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use parameters which will save you from sql injections.

Change your code like below.

```
        string query = "Select seal1 from dbo.RECEIPTHEADER where receipt = @number";

        //define parameters used in command object
        SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@number";
        param.Value         = receiptbox.Text.Trim();

        //add new parameter to command object
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: `code`sealresult.Text = "";
        string connString = @"Data Source=SQL;Initial Catalog=SCESCE;User ID=sa;Password=2b@SCEx!";
        string query = "Select seal1 from dbo.RECEIPTHEADER where receipt = @number";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@number";
        param.Value = receiptbox.Text.Trim();
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);`code`

Comment: I was using something like this before but could not get it to work, however I will play with this some more because I do want to use parameters obviously.  I will post my code in ghostbin and hopefully you can shed some light on it later.. Thanks!